# Quadratic Formula for complex variable with real coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I have been upto proving the following

$$(\forall x\in \mathbb C,  ax^2 + b x + c = 0) \land(a\neq0)\Leftrightarrow \left(x = {\frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}} {2a}}\right)$$

Due to equality we need to prove bi implication,i.e. $a\Rightarrow b$ and $a\Leftarrow b$.It involves just simple arithmetic to go from roots to quadratic equation, but the other way is bit tricky. This is what I have done so far
$$(\forall x\in \mathbb C,  ax^2 + b  x + c = 0) \Rightarrow \left(x = {\frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}} {2a}}\right)$$

$$(\forall x\in \mathbb C,   c = -ax^2 - b  x ) \Rightarrow (2ax = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}} )$$

$$(\forall x\in \mathbb C,   c = -ax^2 - b  x ) \Rightarrow (2ax + b = {\pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}} )$$

Using value of $c$ we get complete square, equation looks like this

$$(\forall x\in \mathbb C,   c = -ax^2 - b  x ) \Rightarrow ((2ax + b) = {\pm \sqrt{(2ax+b)^2} })$$

On this forum I have found discussion on forms like
$$(x  = {\pm \sqrt{x^2} })$$
For complex numbers, I had an impression that it is not true. But it raises question on the goal I am trying to proof.So, if I summarize, I need comments regarding

1-is goal legal?

2-If legal then how to deal with resulting form?

3- If not (1), then looking for some alternative approach to handle it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the fundamental theorem of algebra at your disposal? This would settle equivalence once you've shown that the formula gives the two roots. (Watch out for $b^2-4ac = 0$, though).

Comment: At some point you want to assume the coefficient of $x^2$ is not zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right I have edited the question thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trinomial

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

May be solved when $a,b,c$ are complex numbers, and it works fine with real $a,b,c$, since $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$.

However, we'll start with the real case.

---

**Real resolution**

We start with the equation

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Where $a\neq0$, and $a,b,c\in\Bbb C$.

Then, rewrite the equation

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}=0$$

Then, according to the sign of $\Delta=b^2-4ac$, there are three possibilities:

- If $\Delta=0$, the equation amounts to

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=0$$

It has thus one double root, $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

But since $\Delta=0$, we can also write

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

- If $\Delta>0$, then $\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ is positive, so it's the square of number $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$, and we can write

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)^2=0$$
$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right)=0$$

Hence

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

- If $\Delta<0$, then the equation has no real solution, since it would amount to

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=\frac{\Delta}{4a^2}$$

Where the left-hand side is $\geq0$, whereas the right-hand side is $<0$.

However, we can still write that $\Delta$ is the square of *complex* number $i\sqrt{4ac-b^2}$, hence we can write

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\left(\frac{i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}\right)^2=0$$
$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}\right)=0$$

$$x=\frac{-b\pm i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2a}$$

But, with the convention that $\sqrt{t}=i\sqrt{-t}$ when $t<0$, we can again write

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

So, in all cases, the solutions are

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

Hence your equivalence holds.

---

**Complex resolution**

Again, we start with the equation

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Where $a\neq0$, and $a,b,c\in\Bbb C$.

Then, rewrite the equation

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}=0$$

Now, a complex number $z$ has always a square root (two distinct ones if $z\neq0$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411174/square-roots-of-complex-numbers/411195#411195)). We go on with a square root $\alpha$ of $b^2-4ac$, that is, $\alpha^2=b^2-4ac$, so that the equation can be written

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{4a^2}=0$$

It's a difference of squares, and we know that $A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$, so

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\alpha}{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\alpha}{2a}\right)=0$$

So the roots are

$$x=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{\alpha}{2a}$$

Or if you prefer

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Important note: there is no canonical way to write that $\sqrt{t}$ is a specific square root of $t\in\Bbb C$, hence this symbol is meaningless. However, since it appears with a $\pm$, we will always work with both roots, so using the symbol here is harmless. Nevertheless, it should be avoided.

Comment: S@Jean-Claude Arbaut Thanks for time, I did try this way but I have little problem. As it is allowed to replace $$(\sqrt{{b^2-4*a*c\over 4*a^2}})^2={b^2-4*a*c\over4*a^2}$$     But on removing square root it will give out $2*abs(a)$ which I doubt If I can handle,i.e to replace with "$a$" again.

Comment: @Asad No, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, for *real* $x$, and $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$, for *real* $x\geq0$. More generally, if $\alpha$ is a square root or a (real or complex) number $\beta$, then you always have $\alpha^2=\beta$. That's the definition of a square root!

Comment: @Asad Yes, sorry, I didn't pay enough attention. You can use the usual resolution for the real case then. But actually it's simpler to say $a,b,c$ are *also* complex numbers ($\Bbb R\subset\Bbb C$), and do the complex case of the resolution, since you don't have to manage different cases for $b^2-4ac>0$ and $b^2-4ac<0$ and $b^2-4ac=0$. I'll add this to the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to show that is probably to set
$$z_{\pm} := \frac{-b\pm (b^2-4ac)^{\frac12}}{2a}$$
Where $a,b,c\in\mathbb C$ and see that
$$(z-z_+)(z-z_-) = az^2 + bz + c$$
And finally use the FTA to exclude the existence of any further roots.

Comment: Thanks for hint, please refer some material, it would be appreciated if give some book(s)/publication(s) names to further pursue the idea.

Comment: @Asad What do you have in mind? [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) is about the FTA.