# What is $\sqrt i^i $?

Tags: complex-numbers

my answer would be $i$ because I used the definition $i=\sqrt-1$ and replaced the $i$ with that

I'm not sure if I got it right though

Comment: Do you mean $(\sqrt{i})^i$ or $\sqrt{i^i}$?

Comment: @Wojowu in either case, the result is the same.

Comment: Try considering taking logarithm on both sides of $y=(\sqrt{i})^i$.

Comment: You can see [$i^i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#i_raised_to_the_power_of_i).

Comment: You can see square roots of complex numbers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411174/square-roots-of-complex-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1), in particular $\sqrt{i^i}$.

Comment: Another references for $i^i$ on *this* site is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/how-to-raise-a-complex-number-to-the-power-of-another-complex-number).

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{i}^i=i^{i/2}=\exp \left(\left(\dfrac{\pi i}{2}+2\pi i n\right)\cdot \dfrac{i}{2}\right)=\exp \dfrac{-\pi}{4}\cdot\exp-\pi n, \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Complex exponentiation doesn't work like real exponentiation.  There are infinitely many values of $i^i$ (and two square roots of each.)

Comment: This uses one of the values of $\log i$.  There are many more, which will result in a different value

Comment: @RossMillikan Would adding $2\pi n, \ n\in \mathbb{Z}$ in the expression for $i$ generalize?

Comment: Yes, that's how to get them all.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz I'll edit my answer right away.

Comment: How about $i^{i/2}=\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{i}{2}+2\pi ik\cdot\frac{i}{2} \right)=\exp\left(-\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k\right)\right)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$